# mysql - count of all instances of multiple strings

Tags: mysql, where-in

Let's say there is a table of tie-dye t-shirts for example... Some shirts have multiple colors, listed as a string, comma separated. Such as `blue,yellow,red,purple` or `green,white,black,red`.

I would like to do one query to get a count of how many times each color is present. I **will** know beforehand which 'colors' will exist in the column.

What I'm doing now is a separate query for each 'color':

```
SELECT count(color) WHERE color LIKE '%blue%'
SELECT count(color) WHERE color LIKE '%red%'
SELECT count(color) WHERE color LIKE '%yellow%'
```

etc.....

**Is there a more efficient way of doing this than 15 different queries?**

Example: If my table were to have values for the column 'color' of "`blue, red, yellow`", and another row will be color="`red, green, yellow`" etc...

I'm looking for a query that will return:

```
Blue    Red   Yellow  Green
  1      2      2       1
```

Comment: now you've edited your question, it's kinda complicated do this if you don't have in another table the names of the colors. Because  in that case, a simply join and using aggregate functions, will simplify this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your assertion `I will know beforehand which 'colors' will exist in the column`, what you are looking for is:

```
SELECT
    SUM(color like '%blue%') as total_blue,
    SUM(color like '%red%') as total_red,
    (...)
    SUM(color like '%yellow%') as total_yellow
FROM
    your_table;
```

The `SUM(any boolean condition you want)` is a really nice trick to remember.

Comment: T H A N K Y O U !, I knew it had to be possible. Thank you for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is probably what you are looking for:

```
SELECT
  color.name,
  COUNT(1)
FROM
  foo
LEFT JOIN
  color ON foo.color_id = color.id
GROUP BY
  color.id
```

It would have helped if you'd have given some kind of scheme of how your data looks. This however is the basic solution in such a case.

If you just have color as a string, it's even simpler:

```
SELECT
  color,
  COUNT(1)
FROM
  foo
GROUP BY
  color
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you colors dictionary table is COLORS

```
Select colors.name, count(*) from colors
Join yourtable t on Instr(t.color,colors.name)>0
Group by colors.name
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I'm don't understand this. Why am I joining tables? Thanks!

Comment: This join outputs for example 4 rows for red,blue,yellow,white. So it separates color field to colors. Then you group by colors.name and calculate COUNT for each color from your dictionary.